# How would I sort the numbers without disturbing the format

Tags: perl

**My data file is like this:**

```
* jsdklfjsldkfjlsdkfj
*.AW=351 Tb=sdf c=132  d=53135 s=sdlkfj
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 7
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 3
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 8
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 4
* jsdklfjsldkfjlsdkfj
*.AW=351 Tb=sdf c=132  d=53135 s=sdlkfj
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 7
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 3
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 8
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 4
```

**The Perl code that I have so far is as follows:**

```
open (my $file, "data.txt");
@data=<$file>;
close ($file);

open ($file, ">","data2.txt");
for (@data,undef) { 
if (defined && /^\:.*(\d+)\n/) { 
push @a, [$1,$_]; 
next }
print $file $_->[1] 
for sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } 
splice @a; 
print $file $_ if defined ;
} 
close ($file);
```

**I'm not sure how to find the last number and rank it from small to large.**

**The same data sorted by rank is like this (Final format):**

```
* jsdklfjsldkfjlsdkfj
*.AW=351 Tb=sdf c=132  d=53135 s=sdlkfj
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 3
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 4
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 7
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 8
* jsdklfjsldkfjlsdkfj
*.AW=351 Tb=sdf c=132  d=53135 s=sdlkfj
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 3
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 4
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 7
: A  CC=(111.153.781.36), DD=(111.153.781.36), (sdf_sdf) = 8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $data, "<", "data.txt";
open my $out, ">", "data2.txt";

my @lines;
while (my $line = <$data>) {
    if ($line =~ /^\* number/) {
        print $out $_->[1] for sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @lines;
        @lines = ();
        print $out $line;
    } elsif ($line =~ /^\*/) {
        print $out $line;
    } elsif ($line =~ /^:/ && $line =~ /\s+(\S+)\s*$/) {
        push @lines, [$1, $line];
    } else {
        die "Unknown line! $line";
    }
}
close $data;
close $out;
```

The key bit is the `print $out $_->[1] for sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @lines;` lines, which print out the actual lines after sorting by the number at the end.

Comment: Nit: `\s*\z` would make more sense than `\s*$`.

Comment: Dear @Shawn, sorry, I am new to perl. I do n’t quite understand the meaning of the previous few lines of the code above  `elsif ($_ eq "\n") {
        print $out $_->[1] for sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @lines;
        @lines = ();
        print $out "\n";
    }` 
Why the condition is `$_ eq "\n"`?

Comment: @BillWang Your file format appears to use a blank line to separate groups. So when the script sees a blank line, it prints out the previous lines starting with a colon, but in sorted order. It also does the same after reading to the end of the file, to get the last group.

Comment: Dear @Shawn, If the data is not partitioned by blank lines, that is, if the data is all connected together, how to rewrite the judgment conditions?

Comment: @BillWang If your data is different than what you included as a sample in your question, update the question to reflect the real format.

Comment: Dear @Shawn, I have modified the format of the original data, please take a look again.

Comment: Dear @Shawn, the 'elsif ($_ eq "\n") { print $out $_->[1] for sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @ lines; @ lines = (); print $out "\n";}',  I changed the condition ( '"\n"' to '"\* number of Error ="', but she could n’t catch the line, so the format of the arranged data was wrong. Why?

Comment: Dear @Shawn, Could you please explain push @ lines,[$1,$line]? My understanding is to store a hash into an array named lines, but it seems not quite correct.

Comment: @Shawn note that in his earlier question, the data did not have whitespace before the final number; I recommended there he use Regexp::Common's `$RE{num}{real}` pattern

Comment: Dear @yath, Could you please explain push @ lines,[$1,$line]? My understanding is to store a hash into an array named lines, but it seems not quite correct.

Comment: @BillWang It's something you had in your attempt too... just an array ref stored in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is too greedy.  This is less greedy:

```
if ( defined && /^\:.*=\s+(\S+)\n/ ) {
```

If you print the contents of `@a` before you print to your output file, you will see that it contains only the last digit (0), rather than the whole sci-not number (3.21533e-10), for example.